# Bazel: genrule to touch (create) two files

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to create a genrule that works both on windows and unix that creates two files if they don't exist yet.

for a single file, the following works:

```
genrule(
  name = "create_files",
  outs = ["path/file1.h"],
  cmd_bat = "echo. >> $@",
  cmd = "touch $@",
)
```

but now I'd like to create two files, the following does not seem to work:

```
genrule(
  name = "create_files",
  outs = ["path/file1.h",
          "path/file2.h"],
  cmd_bat = "echo. >> $(OUTS)[0] && echo. >> $(OUTS)[1]",
  cmd = "touch $(OUTS)[0] && touch $(OUTS)[1]",
)
```

I'm getting the error

```
declared output '...path/file2.h' was not created by genrule.
```

How can I do that properly?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the way variable substitution works and the way arrays work in the shell.

In

`cmd = "touch $(OUTS)[0] && touch $(OUTS)[1]"`

Bazel replaces `$(OUTS)` with the paths of the output files, using space for the delimiter. See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/make-variables.html

So the command becomes

`touch path/file1.h path/file2.h[0] && touch path/file1.h path/file2.h[1]`

So you're getting `path/file1.h` touched twice, and two extraneous files.

To make this work, all you need is:

`cmd = "touch $(OUTS)"`

I'm not sure how to do this on Windows for `cmd_bat` though. I'm not aware of a built-in tool that can create multiple empty files like `touch`. You might need to loop over `$(OUTS)` and do `type NUL > file` or something similar.

Comment: I suppose one could run `for` over items in `$(OUTS)` when executing what is essentially a cmd batch.